# What is the Limit Inferior of the sequence ${x}_{n}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, limsup-and-liminf

$x_n = 1 + (-1)^n + \frac{1}{3^n}$

---

Answer to the above question is 
**Two**. Please tell me the proof. Thank you!

Comment: Consider separately odd and even values of  $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be the set of accumulation points of $(x_n)$. Then

$ \lim \inf x_n= \min A$.

We have $x_{2n} \to 2$ as $ n \to \infty$ and  $x_{2n-1} \to 0$ as $ n \to \infty$ . Hence $A=\{0,2\}$.

Comment: Please check it again.

Comment: Answer is 2 not 0

Comment: No. The answer  is  $0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

$$\liminf_{n\to\infty} x_n =\lim_{n\to\infty}\Bigl(\mkern1mu\inf_{k\ge n}x_k\Bigr)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\biggl(\inf_{k\ge n}\Bigl(\mkern1mu\inf_{k\text{ odd}}x_k,\inf_{k\text{ even}}x_k\Bigr)\biggr).$$

Comment: The answer to the above question is 2

Comment: No because $\inf_{k \text{ odd},\: k\ge n}x _k\le\frac1{3^n}$ and $\inf_{k \text{ even},\: k\ge n}x _k\le\frac1{3^n}\ge 2$, hence the $\inf$ of both is $\le\frac1{3^n}$.